# Cannot finish register with register api

Tags: android, api, rest, kotlin, retrofit

excuse me, in this code I want to send data into the database through registerReseller API. when I run this code with the virtual device, it works perfectly. while I run this code with real device, it works as well but some real device doesn't work. when it doesn't work on some device, the app does not crash or force close but stays on that page. Is anybody know how to fix this? Thank you

```
class RegisterFotoResellerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

companion object {
    val IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 1000
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_foto_reseller)

    iv_addimage.setOnClickListener{
        ImageChooser()
    }

}

private fun getRealPathFromURIPath(contentURI: Uri, activity: Activity): String? {
    val cursor: Cursor? = activity.contentResolver.query(contentURI, null, null, null, null)
    return if (cursor == null) {
        contentURI.path
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        val idx: Int = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA)
        cursor.getString(idx)
    }
}

private fun ImageChooser() {
  val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
    intent.type = "image/*"
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val uri = data?.data
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(data?.data)
            .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
            .into(iv_imageperson)
        /*val uriPathHelper = URIPathHelper()
        val filePath = uriPathHelper.getPath(this, uri!!)*/
        //tv.setText(filePath)
        btn_Verifikasi.setOnClickListener {
            val filePath = uri?.let { getRealPathFromURIPath(it, this@RegisterFotoResellerActivity) }
            val file = File(filePath!!)
            val mFile: RequestBody = file.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull()) //membungkus file ke dalam request body
            val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.name, mFile)

            val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val savednohp = sharedPreferences.getString("nohp", null)
            val savedpin = sharedPreferences.getString("pin", null)
            val savednama = sharedPreferences.getString("namaReseller", null)
            val alamatReseller = sharedPreferences.getString("alamatReseller", null)

            val apiService = ApiService.getInstance().create(ApiEndpoint::class.java)
            apiService.uploadimgreseller(body).enqueue(object : Callback<UploadImgResponse> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<UploadImgResponse>, response: Response<UploadImgResponse>) {
                    val responseUpload = response.body()?.link.toString()
                    val apiService2 = ApiService.getInstance().create(ApiEndpoint::class.java)
                    apiService2.registerReseller( savednohp!!, savednama!!, responseUpload, alamatReseller!!, savedpin!!, 0)
                        .enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
                            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
                                val sharedPreferencesLogin = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                                val editor = sharedPreferencesLogin.edit()
                                editor.apply {
                                    putString("login_nohp", savednohp)
                                    putString("login_pin", savedpin)
                                    putString("login_nama", savednama)
                                    putString("login_alamat", alamatReseller)
                                    putString("login_resplink", responseUpload)
                                    putString("login_verified", 0.toString())
                                    putString("login_key", "reseller")
                                }.apply()
                                val intent = Intent(this@RegisterFotoResellerActivity, Dashboard_user::class.java)
                                startActivity(intent)
                                finishAffinity()
                            }

                            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
                                Toast.makeText(this@RegisterFotoResellerActivity, "belum bisa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }

                        })
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<UploadImgResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "durung bisa kyeeehhh")
                }

            })
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: inside `onFailure` you have a log statement which probably isn't going to be useful to you when running on an actual device, you should probably change that to something you can actually see or know about, perhaps make use of a toast or show the user an error dialog so that you know what happened

Comment: ah yaa, why i didn't even think this before? because i only focus on my API script but thanks for the reply and the advice.

Comment: i hope it helps, i haven't gone through the rest of your code so not sure if there's a reason for something else to go wrong but this seems like a valid reason to me